# EtherType multiplexing used by LLC layer

Tags: ethernet, layer2, osi

What's the type of multiplexing used by Ethernet (LLC layer)?

It says in Wikipedia "The LLC sublayer provides multiplexing mechanisms that make it possible for several network protocols (e.g. IP, IPX and DECnet)". I don't understand this multiplexing principle. What do they mean by "multiplexing"?  I can't find the information.

Thanks

Comment: You should read up about EtherType and [SNAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork_Access_Protocol) and then come back when you've got a real question. Homework is explicitly off-topic here, see the [help].

Comment: That's actually not homework. I'm improving my knowledge of Ethernet and I could not find any information about multiplexing. Anyway, thanks for the information

Comment: What you mean by multiplexing used by Ethernet (LLC layer)? - The LLC exists for only one reason - to know if the upper layer is IPv4 or IPv6.

Comment: It says in Wikipedia "The LLC sublayer provides multiplexing mechanisms that make it possible for several network protocols (e.g. IP, IPX and DECnet)". I don't understand this multiplexing principle. What do they mean by "multiplexing" ?

Comment: I'm going to update my question because it's indeed not clear

Comment: @new_py There are quite a few other protocols riding on top of Ethernet, even today.

Comment: Indeed, I'm aware of that. Even more whit the new protocols stack that IoT brings. That the word "mulltiplexing" that bother me. What kind of  "mulltiplexing" the LLC does?

Comment: @ragnar Ethernet is not used exclusively by any upper-layer protocol, e.g. IPv4. You can run all the protocols you want in parallel. Those protocols are multiplexed onto Ethernet on the frame level, using the EtherType value in the frame header (or an additional SNAP header).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplexing is the use of a single communication channel (medium, resource) for multiple, mostly independent purposes. An example from the analog world is a traffic light that could be considered to use time-division multiplexing (TDM) to enable the use of a street crossing for vehicles going in intersecting directions. There are many other forms of multiplexing.

Ethernet frames carry a payload. For multiple types of payload (IPv4, IPv6, IPX, ARP, BPDUs, AppleTalk, PPPoE, ...), their type needs to be specified in a universal way (rather than looking at the payload and trying to interpret it). That way enables some kind of deflector to redirect each frame received by a NIC to the service that handles that type. Without multiplexing, you'd need a dedicated NIC and network for each type of traffic.

With Ethernet, the [EtherType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType) field is used for that purpose or, even more universally, a [SNAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork_Access_Protocol) header.

For example, an IPv4 instance sets the EtherType value for its frames to 0x0800. It passes those frames to a NIC to transmission. On the destination, the frames are received and their EtherType value indicates that they need to be passed to the IPv4 instance there, enabling the IPv4 stacks to talk to each other, without *exclusive* access to Ethernet.

The same happens with IPv6 (EtherType 0x86DD), PPPoE (EtherTypes 0x8863 and 0x8864), or any of the other protocols that can run on top of Ethernet (or another protocol using the same mechanism).

On the other hand, imagine a mail service that transport envelopes between two commercial buildings. As long as there's no writing on the envelopes, the sender may differ but the receiver is always the same. That receiver would have to open the envelope and figure out where to pass the letter on. That might require a lot of guesswork and if the letter is in a foreign language, they'd be lost.

Instead, the sender marks each envelope with a number/name/whatever that unambiguously identifies the intended company in the other building, where the mail person can easily identify the purpose and destination of the letter.

Of course, using a *fully qualified address* on a letter envelope in real life enables us to *multiplex* a single instance of mail service between arbitrary senders and recipients worldwide. Perhaps you could compare the EtherType to writing the destination country on the envelope, enabling delivery even when the actual address is in Chinese.

Comment: I read from wikipedia this text """"The LLC sublayer is primarily concerned with multiplexing protocols transmitted over the MAC layer (when transmitting) and demultiplexing them (when receiving)"""'-----what does mean by demultiplexing?

Comment: Multiplexing (here) means that you use a single link-layer instance but you can use multiple protocols (or instances) on top, (IPv4, IPv6, IPX, LLDP, MSTP, LACP, ...).

Comment: one host could use more than one layer3 protocol at the same time, for example one host could have ipv4 address as well as ipv6 address?

Comment: Yes, any host can use any L3 protocol and any L3 protocol can be used by any subset of hosts. Running IPv4 and IPv6 in parallel is called *dual stack* and pretty much standard today.

Comment: But multiplexing mean more than Ethertype value could be used in one Ethernet frame?

Comment: No, multiplexing works on the frame level, ie. each frame has a single EtherType value and belongs to a single 'next-layer' protocol, often a network layer protocol.

Comment: So multiplexing mean Ethernet frame with l3 protocol type I. e Ethertype?

Comment: @AlokMaity Yes. If you imagine the API the LLC layer might provide it would be something like: def send_l2(ethertype : int, data : bytes) / async def receive_l2(ethertype : int) -> bytes. You could have multiple layer 3 clients using it simultaneously and it would work fine; this is all that multiplexing and demultiplexing means here.

Comment: @richardb multiplexing mean more than Ethertype value could be used in one Ethernet frame at the same time?

Comment: @AlokMaity No. You can imagine a level 2 service that allows fragments from multiple level 3 clients in one frame but it wouldn't be Ethernet.

Comment: @richardb multiplexing mean I use Ethertype, 0x0800, say for ipv4 in Ethernet frame, then demultiplexing means it has multiple receiver, ipv4 as well as ipv6, say?

Comment: @AlokMaity Multiplexing means a single layer-2 instance is used by different higher-layer protocols "simultaneously". The EtherType field is used for demultiplexing = distributing ingress data to those higher-layer protocols. The granularity for "simultaneous" use is the frame level.

Comment: @zac67 "without exclusive access to Ethernet "---- in destination site, receiver doesn't  exclusive access Ethernet?

Comment: Neither "upper-layer" protocol has got *exclusive* access to Ethernet.

Comment: @Zac67 I don't understand ipv4 don't access Ethernet? If ipv4 packets come into layer2 then Ethernet do the next job for transmission.... What do u mean by ""**Ethernet access**""?